# Keycloak evaluate client permissions

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm building a Keycloak extension to allow users create ApiKeys.
Is it possible to evaluate what permissions the user has similar than the UI Admin console:
client -> authorization -> Evaluate

I have tried using the AuthorizationProvider but there is no method to evaluate user permissions.

Using Keycloak V22.

Comment: Can you update your question, which version Keycloak and UI of Evaluate before and after scheen shut?